# Windows 7 Hidden Recovery Partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-restore

Is it possible to copy my recovery partition into another media and restore from it. If it is possible, kindly share the method to perform it. Thanks.

Comment: Any program that generates an image of your hdd will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is possible.

Click the `Start orb` -> `All Programs` -> `Maintenance` -> `Backup and Restore`.

Alternatively, you can get directly  by using [image] + <kbd>R</kbd>, and typing the following into the Run dialog box:

```
sdclt.exe
```

[image]

[image]

The next screen will offer to backup any other volumes you might want to include in the process.

[image]

These articles can help you:

- [Create a Windows 7 System Image for Full Backup](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-windows-7-system-image-for-full-backup-and-restoration/).
- [System Image Disc Recovery](http://archive.benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=439&Itemid=38&limitstart=2).

Comment: Thanks. Very much appreciated. Sorry for the misconception, just want to copy my hidden image partition to a media and make a complete restore of my system. There is something wrong with my current OS - the OEM advance boot doesn't work i.e. press F8 ; "Repair your computer" and nothing happen just start normally.